How to add print scale to UIPrintInteractionController UI interface
I want to add print scale to UIPrintInteractionController UI interface.

example image


what I did achieve with my code
    printControler = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printControler.delegate = self
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
    printInfo.outputType = .general
    printInfo.jobName = name
    printInfo.duplex = .longEdge
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        printControler.showsPaperOrientation = true
    }
    printControler.showsNumberOfCopies = true
    printControler.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true
    printControler.printInfo = printInfo


this


In macOS I can achieve this with
    let options: NSPrintPanel.Options = [.showsPaperSize, .showsOrientation, .showsScaling]
    po.printPanel.options.insert(options)

So is there way to Add scaling controls to UIPrintInteractionController like in the first image? The first image is done via safari mobile.
Thank you.
